# Can I set a custom notification sound for a third party app?

Tags: ios, notifications

I am new to iOS, and am using to being able to set a custom notification sound for third party apps on Android.

Is it possible to do the same on iOS?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the particular third party App on iOS.  For example, you can change the notification sounds for Outlook email notifications. But the limited list of possible choices is made by Outlook not iOS.

This means the developer of each App on iOS is responsible for adding the functionality of setting custom notification alert sounds.